# searching a value in list and return whole line

Tags: python, csv

I want to search for a value in my CSV file and print the whole line

the CSV file like this :

```
some : 111
name : 222
test : 333
```

I using this code :

```
import csv

with open(fin , 'r') as csvfile :
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for line in reader:
        if '222' in line:
            print(line)
```

the problem is its only print the whole line if I search `name: 222`

but if I search only `222` it shows nothing.

I was expecting it when I search 222. print `name: 222`

Comment: line is a list of items -- so if you search for the first item in it you will get the output that you are looking for. Doing  `if '222' in line[0]:` would give the output you are looking for.

Comment: That's not a CSV file. Lines of a CSV file would look like `name,222`. CSV stands for Comma Separated Values but you don't have commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers already provided a solution to this, but let's look at why your solution didn't work.

Csv stands for "comma-separated values", so the csv-reader is expecting each line to be separated with commas (or another delimiter if specified). Since you're using `csv.reader()`, for each line, it returns a list split on commas. For example, the second line is returned as `["name : 222"]`. Naturally, `"222"` is not in this list, but `"name : 222"` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can this code to search value that is a substring of any element in the line.

```py
import csv

# Define the value to search
search_value = '222'

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for line in reader:
        # Check if the search value is a substring of any element in the line
        if any(search_value in element for element in line):
            # Print the entire line
            print(line)
```

You will get the result as a line in the list `['name : 222']`

Answer (score 0):

That's not a CSV file, so don't use the `csv` module to read it. The separator is the string `' : '`, so read the file as lines and call `split()`.

```
with open(fin , 'r') as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        row = line.strip().split(' : ')
        if '222' in row:
            print(row)
```